# Why combining two spark jobs make the performance worse than running them one by one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have two spark utility functions: myUtility1 and myUtility2. They are pretty independent to each other and doesn't matter which one runs first.

If I run:

```
val outData1 = myUtiltity1.process(inputData, utilData1)
```

it took 40 mins. Everything ran smoothly without retry.

If I run:

```
val outData2 = myUtiltity2.process(inputData, utilData2)
```

it tools 20 mins. Everything ran smoothly without retry.

---

However, if I do:

```
val outData1 = myUtiltity1.process(inputData, utilData1)
val outData2 = myUtiltity2.process(outData1, utilData2)
```

The job takes a lot longer than (40+20) = 60 mins, and some tasks in both myUtiltity1 and myUtiltity2 keey retrying. Why is this happening and how do I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you maybe post some of the tasks which are retried and maybe the execution graph? Does myUtility1 or myUtility2 do any caching?

Answer (score 1):

The likely cause of your problem is that `myUtiltity1.process` is doing some caching of your rdds. When you execute `myUtiltity2.process` it is spilling into disk as there is not enough space in memory.

Look at Spark web UI (Storage tab) and check if you have any rdds in memory. Consider modifying your code to release the unused rdds (since you mentioned that these 2 processes are independent) or persist to disk.